# Detect GridView scrolling speed - Android

Tags: android

I have a custom view subclassed from GridView that I use in order to display some custom 3D animation/effect. The way I do this is by overriding `dispatchDraw()`.

Ideally, I'd want to know the current speed of the scrolling when doing the draw. Currently, I use `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and capture `onScroll` events and this works very well, except that it doesn't also detect flings as scrolling events.

One idea that comes to mind would be to capture `onFling` events and then do future processing on my own in order to detect the speed at a later time.

Is there any better way to achieve this? Any simple way to query the current scrolling speed of a GridView?

Thanks.

Comment: Great questions, did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hope you got your answer by now, but I will still post one, for future use...

You will need to override `OnScrollListener`and calculate the speed for yourself.
From Kinematics: `Distance/Time = Speed`

```
private class SpeedDetectorOnScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private long timeStamp;
    private int prevFirstVisibleItem;
    private int scrollingSpeed;

    public SpeedDetectorOnScrollListener () {
        timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastFirstVisibleItem = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeStamp = lastTime;
        lastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        scrollingSpeed =  (firstVisibleItem - lastFirstVisibleItem)/(lastTime-timeStamp)

    }

     public int getSpeed()
     {
       return scrollingSpeed;
     }
 }
```